# Not able to host asp .net web api on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, iis, asp.net-web-api

This could be a very simple thing, but still I am not able to do this. And there is no similar question on SO

I just want to host my asp .net web api over the IIS. I was working with web application years back and this used to be a trivial thing to host a web application (not sure how to host web api).

Please note that when I hit F5 and directly run it from visual studio, then it is correctly getting hosted on IIS express at this address : http://localhost:40343/api/values

I have the default web api created from the asp .net 5 web api template and I have the controller class the following location:

C:\NewLaptopWorkspace\ExRestAPI\src\ExRestAPI\Controllers

Steps I am following:

1. Enabling IIS on my system.
2. Publishing my web api from visual studio using the right click and publish option (I am not sure if this step is even required, I followed this from some of the web tutorial). I am giving the path to publish as : C:\NewLaptopWorkspace\ExRestAPI
3. Adding a website from the IIS. Giving the physical path as the same path where I published my website, i. e. C:\NewLaptopWorkspace\ExRestAPI
4. Changing the .net framework version from the Application Pool to .net 4
5. Now when I try to browse, I get the following error (Please check url, path etc in screen shot below):

[image]

Could someone please help out with this!

Comment: Try to browse where? Show us your controller definitions and perhaps the structure of how you deployed to IIS. Currently, we don't have enough information to help.

Comment: I have just edited my question with more details, please let me know if I should add even more information.

Comment: Could down voter please tell me why?

Comment: Trying navigating to one of your controllers.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I can say that this question lacks sufficient information for people to actually help. It's recommended to provide an [mcve] with your problem so people can construct it on their end if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Try giving the following users access to the physical path:

1. IIS_USRS
2. IUSR

By right click on the folder > security tab > edit.

Answer (score -1):

You are navigating to the root. You need to put in a valid address i.e.  localhost:8080/api/user. Or whatever controller you have setup.

Comment: I tried to navigate this as well: http://localhost:8080/api/values.

Still not working

Comment: Does it work with IIS Express, when you debug right out of Visual Studio?

Answer (score -1):

please try follow these steps:

1. Start IIS Manager. To do this, click Start, click Run, type inetmgr.exe, and then click OK.
2. In IIS Manager, expand server name, expand Web sites, and then click the website that you want to modify.
3. In the Features view, double-click Directory Browsing.
4. In the Actions pane, click Enable.

Comment: Yea, I tried it. But still no luck. I am getting error 404